# extract information from a path

Tags: c#, string

if I have this path A/B//C
I want to extract A,B,C
I was thinking about store index of /,// and extract the values based on the indexes but this create a problem for me since // does not have a single index

```
/ -- index(1)
/ -- index(3)
/ -- index(4) 


    for (int index = 0; index <= path.Length; index++)
    {
            if (path[index] == '/')
            {
                pathIndex[index] = index;
                pathChar[index] = "/";
                Console.WriteLine("Index {0} char{1}", pathIndex[index], pathChar[index]);

            }              

    }
```

but if there is another way which would be shortest and better. I want to know
any effort will be strongly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = "A/B//C";
var splitted = input.Split(new[] { '/' });
for (var idx = 0; idx < splitted.Length; ++idx)
    Console.WriteLine("Index={0} Value={1}", idx, splitted[idx]);
```

If you dont want empty values inside `splitted`, pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to `String.Split`.

Comment: like: A,B,C ---> store them in array for instance , //,/ in another array with their index of string "//" should be deal as an entity not 2 indexes for it... I will highly appreciate your effort

Comment: is there any way to put different delimiters for split method

Comment: Could you clarify on "all information"? And how would you want to handle "A/B,C//D,E/F"? String.Split accepts several delimiters, you could just add more like `new[] { '/', ',' }`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` instead of `'/'` for splitting:

```
string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

string[] parts = currentDirectory.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

foreach (var item in parts)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", currentDirectory.IndexOf(item), item);
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks but I am working with a path in XML documents and I now that there is a XPath in c# but my project enforce me to analyse the xml path.. I think your code "Homam" is very good for file path